# InboxSDK - make sidebarContentPanel collapsed after it's added to threadView

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail, inboxsdk

I'm using InboxSDK to add sidebar to thread view on GMail.

I do it like this:

```
InboxSDK.load(2, 'MY_KEY').then(sdk => {
    sdk.Conversations.registerThreadViewHandler(threadView => {
        const el = document.createElement("div");
        el.id = 'mySidebar';
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, el);

        threadView.addSidebarContentPanel({
            title: 'Sidebar Example',
            iconUrl:chrome.extension.getURL('icon.png'),
            hideTitleBar:true,
            el:el
        });
    });
});
```

But I couldn't find any setting in InboxSDK docs that would enable me to show this panel as collapsed after it's created. Is it possible, or should I do it the dirty way, by adding/removing classes from elements manually?

Answer (score 0):

How about trigger a click event on the button programmatically if the sidebar is opened?

```
if ($('.companion_app_sidebar_wrapper_visible').length > 0) {
    $('.sidebar_thread_iconArea button[data-tooltip="Sidebar Example"]').trigger('click');
}
```